Latex - hide $\label{...}$ when rendering latex
In my latex file, I have a block of code such as:
    \begin{align*}
        \Kmat = \mathbf{V} \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \mathbf{V}^{\intercal} 
        =  \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \dotprodw{\Vv_i}{\Vv_i},        
        \numberthis \label{kmat_eigen_decomp}
    \end{align*}

For some reason the \numberthis \label{...} bit is showing up as follows:

How do I hide the square that says {kmat_eigen_decomp} on the side, while keeping the (A.18) numbering? I tried googling this problem but none of the words I searched for turned up anything. Obviously I cannot just delete the label{...} in code, as I need to reference it later.

[EDIT]
Here's the project link: https://www.overleaf.com/2594224635pvnswvcbkjyh#9644d2
Once the PDF compiles, go to page 8 and find this line:

Or you can find the tex file in sections/chapter2.tex
Here's the .sty page:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


\ProvidesPackage{style}[2019/06/27 Custom LaTeX style]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%% Silence warning about obsolete package
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{remreset}{The remreset package}


%% Standalone
\RequirePackage{standalone}


%% Encoding
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}


%% Fonts and typography
\RequirePackage{lmodern}           % Latin Modern
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}     % Helvetica
\RequirePackage[scaled]{beramono}  % Bera Mono (Bitstream Vera Sans Mono)
\RequirePackage[final]{microtype}  % Improved typography
\pretolerance = 1000               % Relaxes parameters for line breaks
\tolerance    = 2000               % Relaxes parameters for line breaks
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em} % Relaxes parameters for line breaks
\RequirePackage{siunitx}           % Typesetting units
\RequirePackage{listings}          % Typesetting code
\lstset
{
    basicstyle       = \ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle     = \color{gray},
    stringstyle      = \itshape,
    showstringspaces = false,
    frame            = tb
}
\RequirePackage[obeyspaces,
                spaces,
                hyphens]{url}      % Typesetting URLs
\urlstyle{sf}


%% Mathematics
\RequirePackage{amssymb}    % Extra symbols
\RequirePackage{amsthm}     % Theorem-like environments
\RequirePackage{thmtools}   % Theorem-like environments, extends amsthm
\RequirePackage{mathtools}  % Fonts and environments for mathematical formulae
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs}   % Script font with \mathscr{}
\RequirePackage{dsfont}     % Double stroke font with \mathds{}
\RequirePackage{cancel}     % Cancel terms with \cancel, \bcancel or \xcancel
\RequirePackage{stmaryrd}   % Brackets
\everymath
{
    \ifodd\value{page}          % Allow multiline equations
        \allowdisplaybreaks[1]  % to break across two pages:
        \else                   % - Breaks from odd to even pages are allowed,
        \allowdisplaybreaks[4]  %   but discouraged.
    \fi                         % - Breaks from even to odd pages are allowed.
}


%% Language
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}


%% Graphics
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,
                svgnames,
                cmyk]{xcolor}     % Pre-defined colors
\RequirePackage{graphicx}         % Tool for importing images
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\RequirePackage{tikz}             % Drawing tool
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


%% Organising tools
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}                                % Hooks
\RequirePackage{pgffor}                                  % For-loops
\RequirePackage{comment}                                 % Multiline comments
\RequirePackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys}               % Labels in margins
\renewcommand{\showkeyslabelformat}[1]
{
    \fbox
    {
        \parbox[t]{0.6\marginparwidth}
        {
            \centering\normalfont\footnotesize\ttfamily
            \path{#1}
        }
    }
}
\RequirePackage[obeyFinal,
                color       = LightGray,
                bordercolor = LightGray,
                textsize    = footnotesize,
                figwidth    = 0.99\linewidth]{todonotes} % Marginal notes


%% Lists
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]    {font = \upshape,           before = \leavevmode}
\setlist[enumerate]  {font = \upshape,           before = \leavevmode}
\setlist[description]{font = \bfseries\sffamily, before = \leavevmode}
\foreach \env in {theorem, corollary, lemma, proposition, observation,
                  conjecture, definition, example, notation, remark}
{
    \AtBeginEnvironment{\env}
    {
        \setlist[enumerate, 1]{wide,
                               label = \thetheorem.\arabic{*}.,
                               ref   = \thetheorem.\arabic{*}}
    }
}


%% Miscellaneous
\RequirePackage{xspace}         % Clever space
\RequirePackage{textcomp}       % Extra symbols
\RequirePackage{multirow}       % Rows spanning multiple lines in tables
\RequirePackage{tablefootnote}  % Footnotes for tables


%% Bibliography
\RequirePackage{mathscinet}
\RequirePackage[backend    = biber,
                sortcites  = true,
                giveninits = true,
                doi        = false,
                isbn       = false,
                url        = false,
                sortlocale = nb_NO,
                style      = alphabetic]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}
{
    \printfield{volume}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \printfield{number}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \printfield{eid}
}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


%% Cross references
\RequirePackage{varioref}
% \RequirePackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % hide box around ref
\RequirePackage[nameinlink, capitalize, noabbrev]{cleveref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MEMOIR SETTINGS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%% Title page
\pretitle{\begin{center}\huge\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath}


%% Book
\renewcommand*{\printbooktitle}[1]
{
    \hrule\vskip\onelineskip
    \centering\booktitlefont #1
    \vskip\onelineskip\hrule
}
\renewcommand*{\afterbookskip}{\par}
\renewcommand*{\booktitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\booknamefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase}


%% Part
\renewcommand*{\printparttitle}[1]
{
    \hrule\vskip\onelineskip
    \centering\parttitlefont #1
    \vskip\onelineskip\hrule
}
\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{\par}
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase}


%% Chapter
\chapterstyle{demo2}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}
{
    \centering\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}
}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\thechapter\space}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily\center}


%% Lower level sections
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily\raggedright}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath\sffamily\raggedright}


%% Abstract
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\noindent\ignorespaces}


%% Table of contents
\setrmarg{3em}
\setpnumwidth{2em}
\addtolength{\cftbooknumwidth}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftchapternumwidth}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftsectionindent}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftsubsectionindent}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsectionindent}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftparagraphindent}{0.5em}
\addtolength{\cftsubparagraphindent}{0.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnumb}{\bfseries\boldmath}


%% Header and footer
\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruled}{\sffamily\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead {ruled}{}{}{\sffamily\rightmark}
\makeevenfoot{ruled}{\sffamily\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{}{}{\sffamily\thepage}

\makepagestyle{chapter}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{\sffamily\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\sffamily\thepage}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% USER-DEFINED MACROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%% Environments
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont   = \bfseries\sffamily,
                     notefont   = \normalfont,
                     bodyfont   = \itshape,
                     spaceabove = 6pt,
                     spacebelow = 6pt]{plain}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont   = \bfseries\sffamily,
                     notefont   = \normalfont,
                     spaceabove = 6pt,
                     spacebelow = 6pt]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style = plain, numberwithin = section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style = plain,      sibling = theorem]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style = plain,      sibling = theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style = plain,      sibling = theorem]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[style = plain,      sibling = theorem]{observation}
\declaretheorem[style = plain,      sibling = theorem]{conjecture}
\declaretheorem[style = definition, sibling = theorem]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style = definition, sibling = theorem]{example}
\declaretheorem[style = definition, sibling = theorem]{notation}
\declaretheorem[style = remark,     sibling = theorem]{remark}
\crefname{observation}{Observation}{Observations}
\Crefname{observation}{Observation}{Observations}
\crefname{conjecture}{Conjecture}{Conjectures}
\Crefname{conjecture}{Conjecture}{Conjectures}
\crefname{notation}{Notation}{Notations}
\Crefname{notation}{Notation}{Notations}


%% Operators
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}


%% Delimiters
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\p}{\lparen}{\rparen}          % Parenthesis
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}        % Set
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}          % Absolute value
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}         % Norm
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ip}{\langle}{\rangle}         % Inner product, ideal
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sqb}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}        % Square brackets
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ssqb}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket} % Double brackets
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}         % Ceiling
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}      % Floor


%% Blackboard bold
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}    % Natural numbers
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}    % Integers
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}    % Rational numbers
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}    % Real numbers
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}    % Complex numbers
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbb{A}}    % Affine space
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}  % Projective space


%% Bold face
\renewcommand{\a}{\mathbf{a}}
\renewcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}


%% Miscellaneous
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}
\newcommand{\ie}{\leavevmode\unskip, i.e.,\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{\leavevmode\unskip, e.g.,\xspace}
\newcommand{\dash}{\textthreequartersemdash\xspace}
\newcommand{\TikZ}{Ti\textit{k}Z\xspace}
\newcommand{\matlab}{\textsc{Matlab}\xspace}


\endinput


Can you please add a compilable test document to your question?

Are you maybe loading the showlabels package?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hey no Im using this newcommand to define equations: \newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}. I'm working on sharing a version of the project now.

Please add a compilable test document to your question. This will ensure that your question remains useful for future users users with the same problem even if the link stops working.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not sure how to do that. When I try to drag and drop the folder onto the edit field for SO, it doesn't let me attach the entire document. It's template for a thesis, so it's very big.

I have pasted the style.sty page though. The only thing not in there is this line of code: \newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\RequirePackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys}               % Labels in margins

Amazing solved!!

Your .sty file has, amongst others, the line
\RequirePackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys}               % Labels in margins

which will show the label in the margin. If you don't want to show the label in the margin, don't load this package.
